# AuthMember Controller Unit Test AssertionError

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing

I am currently conducting unit tests for the membership registration controller. Below is my code:

1. MemberApiController

```
@PostMapping(value = "/join", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public BaseResponse<MemberResponseDto> join(
            @RequestPart(value = "profileImage", required = false) final MultipartFile image,
            @Valid @RequestPart("requestDto") final MemberSaveRequestDto requestDto
    ) throws IOException {
        final MemberResponseDto result = memberService.saveMember(image, requestDto);

        return BaseResponse.of(
                BaseResponseStatus.JOIN_SUCCESS, // HttpStatus.CREATED
                result
        );
    }
```

2. MemberService

```
 @Transactional
    public MemberResponseDto saveMember(final MultipartFile image, final MemberSaveRequestDto requestDto) throws IOException {
        validateSingUpRequest(requestDto);
        checkPasswordEquals(requestDto.password(), requestDto.checkPassword());

        final String profileImage = saveProfileImage(image);

        final Member member = Member.builder()
                .nickname(requestDto.nickname())
                .profileImage(profileImage)
                .email(requestDto.email())
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode(requestDto.password()))
                .phoneNumber(requestDto.phoneNumber())
                .role(MemberRole.ROLE_GENERAL)
                .status(MemberStatus.ACTIVE)
                .build();

        memberRepository.save(member);

        return new MemberResponseDto(member);
    }
```

3. MemberApiControllerTest

```
@ParameterizedTest
        @AutoSource
        @Customization(MemberSaveCustomization.class)
        void join_success(final MemberSaveRequestDto requestDto) throws Exception {
            // given -- 테스트의 상태 설정
            final MockMultipartFile image = new MockMultipartFile(
                    "profileImage",
                    "profile.jpg",
                    IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE,
                    "test profile content".getBytes(UTF_8)
            );

            final Member member = Member.builder()
                    .nickname(requestDto.nickname())
                    .profileImage(image.getName())
                    .email(requestDto.email())
                    .password(passwordEncoder.encode(requestDto.password()))
                    .phoneNumber(requestDto.phoneNumber())
                    .role(ROLE_GENERAL)
                    .status(ACTIVE)
                    .build();

            final var request = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(requestDto);

            final var response = new MemberResponseDto(member);

            given(memberService.saveMember(any(), any())).willReturn(response);

            // when -- 테스트하고자 하는 행동
            final var result = mockMvc.perform(
                    multipart("/api/members/join")
                            .file(image)
                            .file(new MockMultipartFile("requestDto", "", APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, request.getBytes(UTF_8)))
                            .accept(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                            .contentType(MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
            );

            // then -- 예상되는 변화 및 결과
            result.andExpect(status().isCreated());
        }
```

4. The result of the execution is as follows:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /api/members/join
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8", Accept:"application/json"]
             Body = null
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = custom.capstone.domain.members.api.MemberApiController
           Method = custom.capstone.domain.members.api.MemberApiController#join(MultipartFile, MemberSaveRequestDto)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json", X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY"]
     Content type = application/json
             Body = {"code":1000,"message":"íìê°ìì ì±ê³µíìµëë¤.","result":{"nickname":"test","profileImage":"profileImage","email":"test@test.com","phoneNumber":"010-1234-5678","password":null}}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

Status
Expected :201
Actual   :200
```

As you can see, I have set the returned status value to CREATED (201) when registering for membership, and when I run it in Postman, I also get a 201 status. However, when running the test, I get a 200 status code. Can you help me identify any issues in my code?

Comment: Check BaseResponseStatus Enum: Verify that BaseResponseStatus.JOIN_SUCCESS is indeed set to return a 201 status code. It's possible that during the test, this constant is not set to the expected value.

Comment: Response Entity: Ensure that the BaseResponse.of method is constructing the response entity with the correct status code. It might not be using the status from BaseResponseStatus.JOIN_SUCCESS.

Comment: Global Exception Handling: If you have global exception handling in place, make sure that it's not interfering with the response status of your controller method.

Comment: If everything seems to be in order with the test itself, you might want to debug the test to see the actual response being built and returned by the join method in your MemberApiController. This could give you insights into why the status code is not as expected.